# typerror int object is not iterate

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to write a program for counting of total number of shirts in shop.Here 'shirt' is field containing some int values. I am trying to counting that all values of shirt but its firing an error please check and verify to proceed.

```
shirt = fields.Integer(string='Custom Shirts (Pcs)') 

@api.onchange('shirt')
def shirts_total_count(self):   
    add_shirts=0
    if self.shirt:
        for temp in self.shirt:
            add_shirts=add_shirts+temp.shirt
```

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over an integer field as it will contain only one value. You can only iterate over relational fields of odoo such as **One2many** and **many2many**